# Term for conversion between different tonalities (C major to C minor, etc.)

Tags: theory, terminology, modes, intervals, transposition

***(Inspired by [this recent question](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/95021/45266):)***

If we theorists reserve "transposition" for shifting everything by specific intervals, like every note goes down by a minor 3rd, what do we say when someone transforms a piece in C major to C minor (like by lowering the thirds, etc.) or also potentially shifting everything by generic intervals (CDEFG becomes DEFGA, shifted by diatonic 2nds in the C major scale)?

Is there a term for this that I forgot or cannot recall? Or is there no specific term besides "converting", "transforming", or other general terms?

Comment: "Relative and Parallel Keys" might be the words you look for. I don't understand them enough to write an answer.

Comment: If you stay inside the cyclic group another generic term might be permutation (or group action if it acts on another set)

Comment: Isn't that a reharmonization?

Comment: I'm not convinced, that this process is done frequently enough to have established a well-known word. One reason for this is, that not much of the character of the piece can be preserved during this process.

Answer (score 4):

I think you first want to use the wording *change of mode* to capture the major to minor change. You often read something like "...a change to the minor mode..."

*Modulation* is not a good choice, because the meaning of that word is very clear, and means only a change of tonic without any indication of what happens in the new tonic. I think the typical usage of *modulate* carries the expectation that *new thematic material is presented* in a larger form. You don't modulate a whole song from one tonic to another. A work modulates to a new tonic and introduces a new theme. That is the typical usage.

In contrast to *transpose* - changing the tonic, but not the mode, like *Over the Rainbow* in `A` flat major transposed to `D` major - the wording *reinterpreted in minor* may be a good choice. *Over the Rainbow* reinterpreted in `G` sharp minor.

I think *reinterpret* captures the important point that *choices need to be made about which tones get changed*. Putting the music into the minor mode is not as simple as changing only the major third of a major key to a minor third. The sixth and seventh scale degrees are *variable in minor*, and while there is conventional handling of those two degrees it isn't a matter of hard and fast rules. Different choices could be made for different expressive reasons.

*Translation* seems like a good description too. When a write translates a work of literature from one language to another choices are made for one wording over another. Two translators could translate the same book differently. The same could happen translating a musical work from major to minor. Two musicians could translate the music differently.

Answer (score 1):

This is called **Modulating to a *parallel* key**.  Reference: https://www.musicnotes.com/now/tips/a-complete-guide-to-musical-modulation/.

Answer (score 1):

**Extraneous modulation** is going from one key to an unrelated one. **Parallel modulation** would be a good term for going into the parallel major/minor.

Answer (score 0):

The theory term must be **modal interchange**.

Like a borrowed chord is an example of modal interchange we have here the case that the whole scale adapted to the tune is modal changed.

https://music.tutsplus.com/tutorials/introduction-to-modal-interchange--audio-14142